# Relate exponential to normal distribution and find $E[X^2]$

Tags: probability

The following question is absolutely killing me:

Let $X$ be a continuous r.v. distributed according to the pdf $ke^{-x^2-7x}$. Find $E[X^2]$.

I can supposedly map this onto the Gaussian pdf and use the variance equation to get the answer (i.e., allegedly no integrals required), however, I tried a one-to-one mapping of this pdf onto the Gaussian and came up with an embarrassing mess of algebra. So, I'm not at all sure how the suggested solution is supposed to work. Anyone else understand how to solve this?

Comment: Firstly you have to find the value of k. Have you done that? And what is the domain of $x$?

Comment: Hint: use complete the square

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to find $k$.

Comment: @hunter I think you´re right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's complete the square. We have
\begin{align*}
k\exp(-x^2 - 7x) &= k\exp\big(-x^2 - 7x - \frac{49}{4} + \frac{49}{4}\big) \\
&= k' \exp\bigg(-\big(x+\frac{7}{2}\big)^2\bigg).
\end{align*}
where $k' = k\exp\big(\frac{49}{4}\big)$. We see we have a normal distribution with mean $\mu = -\frac{7}{2}$ and variance $\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then, like you said in the problem statement, we can use the fact that
$$
\sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2,\; \text{ to get }\;
2 =  \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \frac{49}{4} 
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{51}{4}.
$$